# How can I replace the Compass image of MyLocationOverlay?

Tags: android, maps

I want to use my image to replace the Compass image of MyLocationOverlay, how can i implement?

Answer (score 1):

Subclass MyLocationOverlay, override the method drawCompass(Canvas canvas, float bearing), and draw your own bitmap(s) onto the canvas object:

```
@Override
protected void drawCompass(Canvas canvas, float bearing) {

    Resources res = _context.getResources();
    Bitmap myCompassPointer = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.compass_pointer);

    float rotationAngle = -bearing + 360f;
    Matrix rotation = new Matrix();
    rotation.preRotate(rotationAngle, myCompassPointer.getWidth()/2.0f, myCompassPointer.getHeight()/2.0f);

    canvas.drawBitmap(myCompassPointer, rotation, null);

    // don't call super if you don't want the default compass image:
    //super.drawCompass(canvas, bearing);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can only replace the Marker (the blue, pulsating dot) which displays the location, please see [a related StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4175432/mylocationoverlay-change-the-marker). Hope this helps, even if the issue seems a bit old.