# Modifying mylocationoverlay Color in Android

Tags: android, google-maps, location, mylocationoverlay

Is it possible to modify the color scheme of `mylocationoverlay` I want to conver the blinking dot into red color. Please guide me how can I make it possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this related question for the answer - [myLocationOverlay change the marker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4175432/mylocationoverlay-change-the-marker)

Basically, create a subclass of MyLocationOverlay then override drawMyLocation().

There is example code in the related answer.

You can see the API here - http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/MyLocationOverlay.html

Answer (score 1):

Answer can be found here : [myLocationOverlay change the marker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4175432/mylocationoverlay-change-the-marker)